# Updated notification with custom layout changes to default layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I have a custom layout notification which populates some data (distance data).

I have to update the distance in the existing notification.

When I update it , my custom layout changes to default android notification layout.

**New notification creation code.**

```
remoteViews = notificationCustomUI(poi_name, formatDistanceText(poi_type, distance), left_action, right_action, pendingLeftIntent, pendingRightIntent);
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this); // creating new builder for new notification.

            notification = notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.launcher)
                    .setContentText(formatDistanceText(poi_type, distance))
                    .setContentTitle(poi_name)
                    .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingLeftIntent)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setDeleteIntent(getDeleteIntent(notificationId, poi_id, poi_type))
                    .build();
            notification.bigContentView = remoteViews;
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

**Updating exiting notification code**

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_distance, formatDistanceText(poi_type, distance));
 notificationManager.notify(existingNotificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```